# rxdart BehaviorSubject unpredictable behavior

Tags: dart, stream, rxdart

I start using [BehaviorSubject class](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/BehaviorSubject-class.html)

because I need broadcast stream and

> A special StreamController that captures the latest item that has been added to the controller, and emits that as the first item to any new listener.

The test code below:

```
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

void main() {
  BehaviorSubject<int> subject = BehaviorSubject<int>.seeded(0);

  subject.stream.listen((a) => print("listener 1 : $a"));

  subject.add(1);
  subject.add(2);

  subject.stream.listen((a) => print("listener 2 : $a"));

  subject.add(3);

  subject.stream.listen((a) => print("listener 3 : $a"));

  subject.add(4);

  subject.close();
}
```

The result:

```
listener 1 : 0
listener 1 : 1
listener 2 : 2
listener 2 : 3
listener 3 : 3
listener 3 : 4
listener 1 : 2
listener 2 : 4
listener 1 : 3
listener 1 : 4
Exited
```

Although I need the behavior of the instant listens of the stored value of the streams, the result order is so unpredictable to me on what I code.

I need more specifications for the BehaviorSubject class but cannot find out why the stream behaves this way.

I'd like to know how this API works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `BehaviorSubject` is not really a *broadcast* stream. It's a multi-cast stream (multiple listeners), but they don't all get the same events at the same time like a broadcast stream would. (Since they get the latest event at time of listening).

The most likely reason for the displayed behavior (I'm guessing, I haven't checked the `BehaviorSubject` implementation, I just happen to understand Dart streams very well) is that event delivery is asynchronous and events get enqueued.

If you add a `print("done");` after the `subject.close();`, it will print before *any* of the `listener x: y` lines. That's because all the code does until then is to schedule microtasks to later deliver events.

It seems the `BehaviorSubject` schedules one microtask to deliver the first event to each listener (probably calling `onData` directly), then one further microtask the next time a value is `add`ed to the `subject`, which is where it gets added to the listener's event queue. After that, and adding more events to the queue won't trigger more microtasks.
Instead the queue elements will be delivered one by one, requesting a new microtask after each one.

That will give the following behavior (notation: M1:L2[3] means microtask M1 is scheduled to deliver event 3 to listener 2):

```
+─────────────+───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────+──────────────────+
| action      | microtasks                                                                    | prints           |
+─────────────+───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────+──────────────────+
| `listen` 1  | M1:L1[0]                                                                      |                  |
| `add(1)`    | M1:L1[0],M2:L1[1]                                                             |                  |
| `add(2)`    | M1:L1[0],M2:L1[1, 2]                                                          |                  |
| `listen` 2  | M1:L1[0],M2:L1[1, 2],M3:L2[2]                                                 |                  |
| `add(3)`    | M1:L1[0],M2:L1[1,2,3],M3:L2[2],M4:L2[3]                                       |                  |
| `listen` 3  | M1:L1[0],M2:L1[1,2,3],M3:L2[2],M4:L2[3],M5:L3[3]                              |                  |
| `add(4)`    | M1:L1[0],M2:L1[1,2,3,4],M3:L2[2],M4:L2[3,4],M5:L3[3],M6:L3[4]                 |                  |
| `close`     | M1:L1[0],M2:L1[1,2,3,4,DONE],M3:L2[2],M4:L2[3,4,DONE],M5:L3[3],M6:L3[4,DONE]  |                  |
| microtask   | M2:L1[1,2,3,4,DONE],M3:L2[2],M4:L2[3,4,DONE],M5:L3[3],M6:L3[4,DONE]           | `listener 1: 0`  |
| microtask   | M3:L2[2],M4:L2[3,4,DONE],M5:L3[3],M6:L3[4,DONE],M7:L1[2,3,4,DONE]             | `listener 1: 1`  |
| microtask   | M4:L2[3,4,DONE],M5:L3[3],M6:L3[4,DONE],M7:L1[2,3,4,DONE]                      | `listener 2: 2`  |
| microtask   | M5:L3[3],M6:L3[4,DONE],M7:L1[2,3,4,DONE],M8:L2[4,DONE],                       | `listener 2: 3`  |
| microtask   | M6:L3[4,DONE],M7:L1[2,3,4,DONE],M8:L2[4,DONE],                                | `listener 3: 3`  |
| microtask   | M7:L1[2,3,4,DONE],M8:L2[4,DONE],M9:L3[DONE]                                   | `listener 3: 4`  |
| microtask   | M8:L2[4,DONE],M9:L3[DONE],M10:L1[3,4,DONE]                                    | `listener 1: 2`  |
| microtask   | M9:L3[DONE],M10:L1[3,4,DONE],M11:L2[DONE]                                     | `listener 2: 4`  |
| microtask   | M10:L1[3,4,DONE],M11:L2[DONE]                                                 |                  |
| microtask   | M11:L2[DONE],M12:L1[4,DONE]                                                   | `listener 1: 3   |
| microtask   | M12:L1[4,DONE]                                                                |                  |
| microtask   | M13:L1[DONE]                                                                  | `listener 1: 4   |
| microtask   |                                                                               |                  |
+─────────────+───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────+──────────────────+
```

You can see this matches your result. So, things work the way they do because of the way they're implemented, and because it's relying on an event enqueuing which puts itself at the back of the microtask queue after delivering each event, so the longest queue gets done last.

You can explore the behavior yourself by printing when microtasks are scheduled and run:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

void main() {
  int ctr = 0;
  runZoned(() {
    BehaviorSubject<int> subject = BehaviorSubject<int>.seeded(0);

    print("listen 1");

    subject.stream.listen((a) => print("listener 1 : $a"), onDone: () {
      print('listener 1 done');
    });
    print("add 1");
    subject.add(1);
    print("add 2");
    subject.add(2);
    print("listen 2");
    subject.stream.listen((a) => print("listener 2 : $a"), onDone: () {
      print('listener 2 done');
    });
    print("add 3");
    subject.add(3);
    print("listen 3");
    subject.stream.listen((a) => print("listener 3 : $a"), onDone: () {
      print('listener 3 done');
    });
    print("add 4");
    subject.add(4);
    print("close");
    subject.close();
    print("done");
  }, zoneSpecification: ZoneSpecification(scheduleMicrotask: (s, p, z, f) {
    var id = ++ctr;
    print("Schedule microtask $id");
    p.scheduleMicrotask(z, () {
      print("Run microtask $id");
      f();
    });
  }));
}
```

which prints:

```
listen 1
Schedule microtask 1
add 1
Schedule microtask 2
add 2
listen 2
Schedule microtask 3
add 3
Schedule microtask 4
listen 3
Schedule microtask 5
add 4
Schedule microtask 6
close
done
Run microtask 1
listener 1 : 0
Run microtask 2
listener 1 : 1
Schedule microtask 7
Run microtask 3
listener 2 : 2
Run microtask 4
listener 2 : 3
Schedule microtask 8
Run microtask 5
listener 3 : 3
Run microtask 6
listener 3 : 4
Schedule microtask 9
Run microtask 7
listener 1 : 2
Schedule microtask 10
Run microtask 8
listener 2 : 4
Schedule microtask 11
Run microtask 9
Run microtask 10
listener 1 : 3
Schedule microtask 12
Run microtask 11
listener 3 done
listener 2 done
Run microtask 12
listener 1 : 4
Schedule microtask 13
Run microtask 13
Schedule microtask 14
Run microtask 14
listener 1 done
```

(The "done" are delayed, probably because they need to wait for another future.)

Comment: lrn Thanks a lot for the detail!! I will study from now. Really appreciated!